# How do I add an element behind the x-axis label text on a graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've made some code to draw a scatterplot, where each tick on the x axis is a gene name. That's all working fine. What I want is for the user to click on any gene name to be taken to an info page about it. More explicitly, I'd like to have a rectangle (or some shape) appear behind the label on mouseover, and for that shape (and the text itself) to act as a link to the external web page.

As the axis is created by D3 itself I can't change the `text` objects to `a` objects with a link property (or can I?), so somehow I need to add a bunch of children to the axis object, before the text objects so they're drawn behind, that have the ability to be links. Here's some of my code where the x axis is actually created (works fine):

```
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(-65)" });
```

I've tried a few different things, most recently:

```
d3.select(".x").data(genenames)
    .insert("rect", "text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d); } )
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("width", "20")
    .attr("height", "10")
    .style("fill", "blue");
```

But the browser complains with: `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.` It's something about that `.insert` call I think. I'm still learning javascript so maybe there's something obvious I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure this one out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the axis `g`, I think you need the ticks `g`s.

How about this:

```
var genenames = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]    

d3.selectAll(".tick").data(genenames)
    .insert("rect", "text")
    .attr("x", 0 )
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("width", "20")
    .attr("height", "10")
    .style("fill", "blue");
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QbHB5ZUZeLnU92HAmp7R?p=preview).

Comment: Ah right you are, thank you. There was one quirk though; if I set `.attr("y", height)` the rectangles did not display (or they were off the screen at the bottom). I instead used the same y value as the text objects, which happened to be 9 and it all worked. Thanks!